# How does `Tcl_Free()` differ from `free()`?

Tags: c, tcl

The descriptions seem virtually identical. Are there any nuances between the two that should be noted? Why would someone use one over the other? This question may be imposed as well for `Tcl_Alloc()` and `malloc()`.

Comment: From the manpage: _These procedures provide a platform and compiler independent interface for memory allocation._ So it might also be ported to platforms, that do not support the `malloc()` interface without changing the source. Indeed it might just call `malloc()` on most platforms. Or it may also additionally collect memory statistics: _When Tcl and all modules calling Tcl are compiled with TCL_MEM_DEBUG defined, however, these macros are redefined to be special debugging versions of of these procedures._

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/3/tcl_alloc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They're used because Tcl supports being built on Windows with one tool chain, and loading a DLL built with a different toolchain. A key feature of that scenario is that it is fairly common for different toolchains to have their own implementations of the C library, and that means *different implementations of `malloc()`*. You *must* match `malloc()` and `free()` to the same library or you get some truly weird failures (crashes, memory leaks, etc.) By providing `Tcl_Alloc` and `Tcl_Free` (which are usually very thin wrappers) it makes it possible for user code to match up the allocations and releases correctly.

Answer (score 1):

This is normally the most obvious reason to do that:

Normally, the best understood reason to use your own version of the memory allocation functions is to have a single definition that allows you to change the memory allocator for a different allocator. (a debugging, extended, or implemented with security options, etc.)

Just assume you have the following implementation:

```
void *my_malloc(size_t siz)
{
    return malloc(siz);
}

void my_free(void *ptr)
{
    free(ptr);
}
```

defined in `allocator_malloc.c`

and for a special customer X you have acquired a license of the new ACME allocator.  For this customer you link your executable with the file `allocator_ACME.c`  which contains:

```
void *my_malloc(size_t siz)
{
    return ACME_malloc(siz);
}

void free(void *ptr)
{
    ACME_free(ptr);
}
```

Then, just linking your executable with one or the other file, you generate a dependency of the standard library `malloc()`, or you'll have to provide an implementation of `ACME_malloc()` function.  In this way, just changing the presence of one of several object files, changes the whole set of dependencies (assuming you have definitions for both `my_malloc()` and `my_free()` in your source file) into one of several different implementations.

The drawback is that you have one level of function call more, so in some cases a more sofisticated solution has to be used.

Assume that you buy an automatic garbage collector, so you don't need to return the memory allocated with malloc, as for some magic, the library will detect that you have not used it more, and it garbage collects it automatically:

```
void *my_malloc(size_t siz)
{
    return GC_malloc(siz);
}

void my_free(void *ptr)
{
    /* empty */
}
```